# Apply visualization settings to different graphs

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

Is there any way to apply the same visualization settings (node colors, layout, etc.) to different graphs (without doing it for every graph)?

The only way I found is to redo the same settings every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to … without doing the visualization steps every time for every graph?

Settings for `Preview` -tab can be saved:

`Preview` > `Preview Settings` > `Presets` > `Save preset`

Nothing set from `Overview` -tab is saved this way. Using a pre-saved, empty (read-only) .gephi document for new graphs may help (for color schemes, filter settings, etc.).